# How to setState array of objects in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I fetch a list of files from backend and push it to the array of objects (dirloc) in component state. At the moment console log shows multiple logs of dirloc for each file. 
I want to setState once everything is pushed to the dirloc. How to do it?

```
    class Load extends Component {
      constructor({ props, token }) {
        super(props, token);
        this.state = {
          nodeRes: [],
          dirloc: []
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://192.168.22.124:3000/loadit/", {
          headers: new Headers({
            authorization: `Bearer ${this.props.token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          })
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(logit => {
            let { dirloc, nodeRes } = this.state;
            logit.map(verifypath => {
              let getpath = verifypath.substring(0, verifypath.lastIndexOf("/"));
              let dirnames = getpath
                .toString()
                .split("/")
                .pop();
              return getpath !== ""
                ? (dirloc.push({
                    getpath: getpath /* for e.g '/folder/of/files/' */,
                    dirnames: dirnames /* array of folder names */,
                    ffiles: verifypath /* full path '/folder/of/files/abc.jpg' */
                  }),
                  this.setState({ dirloc }, () => {
                    console.log(this.state.dirloc);
                  }))
                : (nodeRes.push(verifypath), this.setState({ nodeRes }));
            });
          })
          .then(getdata => this.allFetch(this.state.nodeRes));
      }

    }

    render() {
    const {  dirloc } = this.state;
    let folderView;
    for (var i = 0; i < dirloc.length; i++) {
     if (Object.entries(dirloc).length !== 0 && dirloc.constructor !== Object) {
       folderView = <Filetree fileloc={this.state.dirloc} token={this.props.token} />
    console.log(`dirs: ${dirloc[i].getpath}`)
    } else {
        folderView = null
    }
  }
```

**Edit:**  The problem is that when I render with conditional statement, I see that console log shows object multiple times which means it renders child component multiple times. I want to render it once only with all the required objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the required values first and then invoke setState once at the end.

```
fetch('http://192.168.22.124:3000/loadit/', {
  headers: new Headers({
    authorization: `Bearer ${this.props.token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((logit) => {
    const { dirloc, nodeRes } = this.state;
    const newDirLoc = [];
    const newNodeRes = [];
    logit.forEach((verifypath) => {
      const getpath = verifypath.substring(0, verifypath.lastIndexOf('/'));
      const dirnames = getpath.toString().split('/').pop();
      getpath !== ''
        ? newDirLoc.push({
          getpath,
          dirnames,
          ffiles: verifypath,
        })
        : newNodeRes.push(verifypath);
    });
    this.setState({
      nodeRes: [...nodeRes, ...newNodeRes],
      dirloc: [...dirloc, ...newDirLoc]
    })
  });
```

At the render, check for the condition before the loop.

```
render() {
  const { dirloc } = this.state;
  let folderView;
  if (dirloc.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < dirloc.length; i++) {
      folderView = <Filetree fileloc={this.state.dirloc} token={this.props.token} />;
      console.log(`dirs: ${dirloc[i].getpath}`);
    }
  } else {
    folderView = null;
  }
}
```

Have replaced Object.entries with a simple length check as dirloc is an array.

Comment: I have updated my question. The problem is that when I render with conditional statement, I see that console log shows object multiple times which means it renders child component multiple times. 
I want to render it once only with all the required objects.

Comment: Updated answer with render method although I am not sure why a loop is being used here, as none of the loop variables is used inside the block apart from console.log.  
Also as a thumb rule, even if react's setState is asynchronous and batches all statements before execution, it is best to invoke it as minimal times as the async behaviour can't be controlled and it might result in multiple re-renders if your calculations are time consuming.

Comment: I have another question related to this, can I ask here?